JavaScriptCore crash during JSObjectCallAsFunction on IOS 13 IOS14 AND IOS 17
The entry function calls of the crash stack are all JSObjectCallAsFunction, but the subsequent crash location is different on each system. We have suspected a memory problem, but the device still has a lot of available memory. In addition, this method will be called frequently and debugging will take a long time. It only happens once in a while that I don’t have any troubleshooting ideas.
This is the crash stack on ios17, Could it be related to the release of certain variables? Or is there some hard-to-find problem with javascriptcore？
JavaScriptCore
JSC::JSFinalObject::visitChildren(JSC::JSCell*, JSC::SlotVisitor&)
1
JavaScriptCore
JSC::SlotVisitor::drain(WTF::MonotonicTime)
2
JavaScriptCore
JSC::SlotVisitor::drain(WTF::MonotonicTime)
3
JavaScriptCore
JSC::Heap::runFixpointPhase(JSC::GCConductor)
4
JavaScriptCore
JSC::Heap::runCurrentPhase(JSC::GCConductor, JSC::CurrentThreadState*)
5
JavaScriptCore
WTF::ScopedLambdaFunctor<void (JSC::CurrentThreadState&), JSC::Heap::collectInMutatorThread()::$_23>::implFunction(void*, JSC::CurrentThreadState&)
6
JavaScriptCore
JSC::callWithCurrentThreadState(WTF::ScopedLambda<void (JSC::CurrentThreadState&)> const&)
7
JavaScriptCore
JSC::Heap::collectInMutatorThread()
8
JavaScriptCore
JSC::Heap::stopIfNecessary()
9
JavaScriptCore
JSC::LocalAllocator::allocateSlowCase(JSC::Heap&, unsigned long, JSC::GCDeferralContext*, JSC::AllocationFailureMode)
10
JavaScriptCore
_llint_slow_path_new_func_exp
11
JavaScriptCore
_llint_function_for_construct_arity_checkTagGateAfter
12
JavaScriptCore
_llint_function_for_construct_arity_checkTagGateAfter
13
JavaScriptCore
_vmEntryToJavaScriptTrampoline
14
JavaScriptCore
JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&)
15
JavaScriptCore
_JSObjectCallAsFunction
16
**APPNAME**
script::jsc_backend::toJscValues<script::Local<script::Value>, script::Local<script::Function>::callImpl(script::Local<script::Value> const&, unsigned long, script::Local<script::Value> const*) const::$_0>(OpaqueJSContext*, unsigned long, script::Local<script::Value> const*, script::Local<script::Function>::callImpl(script::Local<script::Value> const&, unsigned long, script::Local<script::Value> **APPNAME**const*) const::$_0)::{lambda(OpaqueJSValue const**)#1}::operator()(OpaqueJSValue const**) const JscHelper.hpp:36
17
**APPNAME**
script::Local<script::Function>::callImpl(script::Local<script::Value> const&, unsigned long, script::Local<script::Value> const*) const JscLocalReference.cc:498

An occasional issue that occurs when calling JSObject CallAsFunction frequently, with many instances on IOS13, IOS14, and IOS17.4.1, without any solution
